# IIS, SiteCore, Url redirecting when calling folder

Tags: iis, sitecore

I'm working with SiteCore 6.4 and I've setup a hook in the ParseUrl method for the LinkManager. It's all working except for one problem, when I call a url that contains a folder, the HttpRequest I end up getting strips off the directory.

Works: http://domain/

If I call http://domain/state/page.aspx the request I get has the URL as http://domain/page.aspx. If I manually change the url (in debug mode) to include what I wanted then everything works fine.

There is something in the pipeline that is redirecting the url. Where is it? How do I prevent it? There used to be a setting in IIS 5/6 to disbale file exists checks, is there the same in IIS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your 'state' is a 2 letter abbreviation. If that's the case, try setting 'languageEmbedding="never"' in the web.config for your LinkManager. I had similar problem. It tries to interpret your 2 char state as the language, ie: en, sp etc. At least, this is what I think. It fixed the issue I had.

Comment: That did the trick! How annoying. So basically, I wouldn't be able to include language (at least built in sitecore language) features because of this?

Comment: You can set the languagelocation to querystring instead of the filepath. bascially it wont be considered in the URL, instead it will look in the querystring. not as good as in the url IMO but oh well.

Comment: Slightly better than using the query string would be setting up parallel hostnames in the web-config e.g. en.mysite.com fr.mysite.com. Still a workaround, but will give better SEO than using the query string.